# Whats wrong with this method?

Tags: java, recursion, tail-recursion

Here's the method:

```
public static String CPUcolor () 
{ 
    System.out.println ("What color am I?") ; 
    String s = getIns() ; 
    System.out.println ("are you sure I'm "+s+"? (Y/N)") ; 
    String a = getIns() ; 
    while (!((a.equals ("y")) || (a.equals ("Y")) || (a.equals ("n")) || (a.equals ("N")))) 
        {
            System.out.println ("try again") ; 
            a = getIns () ; 
        } 
    if (a.equals ("n") || a.equals("N"))
        {CPUcolor() ;} 
    System.out.println ("I am "+s) ;
    return s ; 
}
```

here is a possible output of this method (y's and n's are user inputs):

> ```
> What color am I?
> red
> are you sure I'm red? (Y/N)
> N
> What color am I?
> blue
> are you sure I'm blue? (Y/N)
> N
> What color am I?
> Yellow
> are you sure I'm Yellow? (Y/N)
> y
> I am Yellow
> I am blue
> I am red
> ```

Why is it that the line's "I am blue" and "I am red" printed? Why are they printed in reverse order with red, the first entered, printed last?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611573#2611589 why recursion is plain wrong for this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's simple [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion). You are calling `CPUcolor()` within your `CPUcolor()` again. When the call returns, the remaining commands of each original method will be executed.
To fix it you have to add a return:

```
if (a.equals ("n") || a.equals("N"))
{
  return CPUcolor();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Note that

```
    if (a.equals ("n") || a.equals("N"))
        {CPUcolor() ;} 
    System.out.println ("I am "+s) ;
```

should be:

```
    if (a.equals ("n") || a.equals("N"))
        {CPUcolor() ;} 
    else
        {System.out.println ("I am "+s) ;}
```

This way you **only print the color** in the single instance **when the user actually answered `Yes`** (you do not want to print the color for those instances when the user answered `No`, instances which you **revisit in reverse order as you [unwind your recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion)** -- the reason for the reverse order in which the other answers were printed.)

Also note that **you do not need (nor want) recursion** in this particular example: once you add the `else` your method becomes [tail-recursive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29#Tail-recursive_functions), and you can achieve the same effect [iteratively](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29#Recursion_versus_iteration).  By eliminating recursion you also eliminate a vulnerability problem, that is, the possibility of a malicious user entering `No` indefinitely until your program eventually **crashes with a [`StackOverflow`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611573#2611589)`Exception`**:

```
public static String CPUcolor () 
{ 
  while (true) {
    System.out.println ("What color am I?") ; 
    String s = getIns() ; 
    System.out.println ("are you sure I'm "+s+"? (Y/N)") ; 
    String a = getIns() ; 
    while (!((a.equals ("y")) || (a.equals ("Y")) || (a.equals ("n")) || (a.equals ("N")))) 
        {
            System.out.println ("try again") ; 
            a = getIns () ; 
        } 
    if (a.equals ("y") || a.equals("Y")) {
      System.out.println ("I am "+s) ;
      return s ; 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have indented the output, to help make it a little bit clearer, what's happening:

```
What color am I?
red
are you sure I'm red? (Y/N)
N
    What color am I?
    blue
    are you sure I'm blue? (Y/N)
    N
        What color am I?
        Yellow
        are you sure I'm Yellow? (Y/N)
        y
        I am Yellow
    I am blue
I am red
```

Every level of indentation is one level deeper in the call hierarchy: one more call to CPUColor(). After a call to CPUColor() returns, the rest that follows still has to be done.

I like to view it similarly to the folders in a file directory tree: Just imagine folding and expanding the lower levels of directories!

Answer (score 0):

Because you're calling the new CPUColor() before printing out the results of this one.